# Lowering my chest note

Tags: voice-training

I am 19 and my lowest note is F2(breathy). I want to increase my lower chest range. Any suggestion. For lowering it down further.

Comment: Grow older;) Give it another 20 years & you'll be wondering where the top of your range went, instead of worrying about the 3rd you gained at the bottom.

Comment: Are you taking lessons?  Get a professional classical voice coach.  All I can think of is support with the diaphragm, proper mouth shape, posture.  It is all very internal.  No way to help via chat messages except to say take lessons with a classical voice coach.  You may be frequency limited by your size.  Other than proper relaxed practice I don't know any "tricks" to extend range.

Comment: @ Tetusjin: get older, was my first reflection too.

Comment: Just keep doing descending scale runs in your vocal warmup. You'll get more comfortable in your lower range that way. I generally sing down to C#2 or D2 but when I'm particularly relaxed and warmed up I can hit as low as a Bb1. When I was your age my lower range was Eb2-F2 so I second the growing older comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lay on your bed, the head outside the bed end. Let your head hang down, breath deep in and out. Shake your head, than hold your chin on your breast.

(by this exercise you stretch and enlarge your vocal chords)

Comment: This is an interesting idea, do you have any citation for this?

Comment: Head and neck gym is a standard warm-up I used as choir leader.

Comment: How may sets or reps?

Comment: each time you before you start singing. Do it slowly, like your breathing, counting 1,2,3,4, in seconds, if you do repeat it 6-10 times it will last min. 50 seconds (in groups). If you do it alone you can also practice to let hanging your head as long you feel comfortable, stop before your head  falls down or you have a neck like a giraffe.